# Create regular expression which satisfy multiple conditions

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to create a regular expression using the below restriction, but maybe I am missing something, because it creates a wrong output.

Restrictions:

1) String shouldn't contain numbers only

2) String shouldn't contain more than 3 special characters

3) String has not any word (substring) which has length more than 10 characters

4) String length must be 3 or greater

I have created a regex which solves the 1st point:

```
/^\d*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d]*$/
```

But I failed with adding the other restrictions 2-4.

Comment: I don't understand all of your restrictions: 1) You want that your string can not contain only numbers? 2) What are "special" characters? 3) Don't understand point 3 at all (Guess: 10 characters behind each other is not allowed?!)

Comment: 1) whole string should not have only numbers  2) string should not have more than 3 special characters ($,&,%,@)     3) string has many words so each words length should less than 10 characters.   4) whole string length must not less than 3 characters.

Comment: 4. Use strlen(), it will be much easier and will be easier to read.

Comment: @Andreas i want all using regular expression.

Comment: Ok... in that case you need to use {3,}

Comment: @Andreas  can you make one full regular expression for that 4 points

Comment: Try [`^(?!\d+$)(?!(?:\w*\W){4})(?!.*\b\w{11}).{3,}$`](https://regex101.com/r/lD3gA7/1). If your "word" should consist of non-whitespace symbols, change `\b\w` to `\b\S`. Please add some sample strings that should be valid and some strings that should be invalid.

Comment: great @WiktorStribiżew  it works fine except point 3. can you please add point 3 that up to 3 special character is allow but more than 3 special character is present in string than does not match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a regex like

```
^(?!\d+$)(?!(?:[^$&%@]*[$&%@]){4})(?!.*\b\w{11}).{3,}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lD3gA7/2)

Pattern breakdown:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!\d+$)` - there must not be only digits (`\d+`) up to the end of string (`$`)
- `(?!(?:[^$&%@]*[$&%@]){4})` - there must not be 4 sequences of 0+ non-special characters (`[^$&%@]*`) followed with a special character
- `(?!.*\b\w{11})` - there must not be a word having 11 word characters (`\w{11}`) after a word boundary (`\b`)
- `.{3,}` - 3+ any characters
- `$` - end of string

Comment: hey @wktor  you are great. this is working great. thank you very much

Comment: hi can you please convert above regular expression for mysql query compatible. because i am getting error : Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp. when use in mysql query

Comment: It is impossible, MySQL REGEXP does not support lookarounds.

Comment: You can split the conditions though, something like `WHERE col REGEXP '^.{3,}$' AND col NOT REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' AND col NOT REGEXP '([^$&%@]*[$&%@]){4}' AND col NOT REGEXP '[[:<:]][[:alnum:]_]{11}'`

Comment: Glad it worked for you. If you found my answer helpful please also consider upvoting.